# How do I use Windows Easy Transfer to copy all my settings to Windows 8?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, windows-easy-transfer, easy-transfer

How can I use Windows Easy Transfer to copy all my settings and files to Windows 8, from Windows 7?

Answer (score 1):

1. Start Easy Transfer on Win7
2. Select one of the following options (the first two are obviously not valid if you are going to upgrade the same PC, so I'll just describe the third one):

   [image]
3. Select all the options such as files in your Libraries, Program Settings, Windows Settings etc. that you want to transfer (for your own custom locations browse using the *Advanced* link)
4. Enter a password to protect the data, then wait for the transfer to complete
5. On the Win8 PC (after the upgrade) start Easy Transfer, then select the 3rd option above
6. Select the Easy Transfer file on the external drive, enter the password when prompted and wait for the transfer to complete

That should do it!